# Could flower heads be a sustainable primary food source for a species of omnivorous lizards?

Tags: biology, food, reptiles

While they 'technically' aren't lizards, these are very physiologically similar creatures that are pretty small (about the size of a hand) and lead very sedentary lives, mating opportunistically and only in specific conditions, and avoiding predation by just laying very still under a rock or tree roots. I also imagine that they are omnivorous to back up their flower-based diet by scavenging dead animals and eating insects and berries, for example, as secondary sources of nutrients.

Would this diet provide the necessary nutrients to support these creatures? I know there aren't exactly many calories in flower petals or the rest of the flower head for that matter, so could there be certain qualities added to the flowers that could better sustain them or make them more attractive sources of nutrients?

Comment: If my iguana is any indication, yes (although leaves are preferred due to higher nutritional density, but look up hibiscus). What research did you perform before asking? Stack Exchange expects you to do your due diligence and not simply use its Stacks as free research services.

Comment: @JBH I couldn't find much on flower head nutrient density, but what I did find seemed to point in the same general direction you suggest; the leaves are more nutrient dense than the petals or reproductive structures and thus preferred.

Comment: Do plants in this setting flower all year round? If not, flower heads will only be available during flowering season, which makes it hard to base a diet on them.

Comment: Make them eat lotus flowers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lotos-Eaters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

The biggest problem with flowers as a food source is not lack of nutrients, but the fact that they tend to be seasonal, and only last for a short period of time compared to other plant based food sources like leaves or roots which are generally available year round. Many plants only flower for a few weeks out of the year before going dormant again.  That said, different plants flower at different times of year, so as long as it eats a very wide range of flowers, it should be doable.

Also of note, most animals that feed on seasonal parts of plants like flowers, fruits, and nuts tend to only rely on those parts of the plant for a nutritional boost during times of plenty, but still eat other things the rest of the year.  However, being a reptile means it may not need to.  Cold blooded animals like lizards can go months between meals, especially during the cold season when you would not have your flowers.

Lastly, don't worry too much about the exact nutritional qualities of a flower.  Every animal is adapted to live off the food source it eats.  While humans may need to get things like Vitamin-C and Omega-3 from our food, many other animals can actually make these things themselves without needing to rely on dietary sources.  If there are any nutrients your lizard needs that flowers are low in, assume your lizard has a way to make them itself, or uses it in small enough of amounts to get by off of what flowers have.

[image]

Comment: Some animals eat almost exclusively carbohydrates. Some eat no carbs. Some people go months at a time eating mostly animal fat. They are adapted to this diet so the limiting factor is the calorie count.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I hadn't considered how animals adapt around their diets. The fact that flowers are seasonal as well was also something I had not considered.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

[image]

Ripe sunflower heads are packed with  seeds. Sunflower Seeds. Sunflower seeds are packed with calories. They can be the diet foundation of any species that is evolved to eat them.

[Image Source](https://www.scoular.com/grains-seeds-products/sunflower-seeds/)

Answer (score 1):

**Dandelions**

Their whole flowers were welcome addition to human food, are nutritious and tasty. They were forgotten and unjustly shunned as food of the poor.

Also, all kinds of insects that are predatory, like ladybugs, supplement their diet with pollen and are attracted to flowers with accessible pollen (again dandelions, marigold,...)

Plus consider everything that lives off the nectar, you can put to rest any doubts about flowers being nutritionally rich.

Answer (score -1):

hummingbirds manage it somehow.  Thety don't eat the whole flower-head though, so they aren't competing against the flowering plant.